# Why nodejs console.log only showing " ... "?

Tags: node.js, console.log

I have this in helloworld.js :

```
console.log('Hello World');
```

and the output is :
http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/4152/8vh3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using REPL of node.js.

You should run such command directly in CMD.

[image]

By the way, you can input raw code, like `console.log('Hello')` in REPL.

Answer (score 0):

This should be run directly from command line interface as mentioned by @Chichou. If you want to test such things you can also use browser console.